# How to use a variable to get the current directory path correctly? Trying to run a virus scanner to scan the current directory from context menu

Tags: windows, variables, cmd, registry, working-directory

I can use the variable `%CD%` to run a command-line virus scanner to scan the current directory from command prompt like this.

```
C:\AVPTool\AVPTool.exe SCAN %CD% /R:KAVSCANLOG.txt
```

I'd like use it from context menu to easily scan the folder with just two clicks.

I modified the registry and created a key called `Scan with AVPTool` in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` and within that key I created another key called `command` and changed the value to

```
"cmd.exe /k cd %1 & C:\AVPTool\AVPTool.exe SCAN %CD% /R:KAVSCANLOG.txt"
```

But this doesn't work since `%CD%` doesn't get translated into the current working directory.

Comment: Does the first part (cd %1) work? If so, why do you need %CD% when you can just write %1 again?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thanks, now it's working. The correct command reads:   `cmd.exe /c cd /d %1 &&  C:\AVPTool\AVPTool.exe SCAN %1  /i9 /R:KAVSCANLOG.txt && start notepad "%1/KAVSCANLOG.txt"`

Answer (score 1):

I'd try

```
"cmd.exe /k cd %1 & C:\AVPTool\AVPTool.exe SCAN "%1" /R:KAVSCANLOG.txt"
```

since the line would be processed by replacing the %-variables and **THEN** executed, %CD% would be replaced by whatever the current directory of the INVOKING process is, not the directory in which the process is RUN. The current directory is only changed AFTER the `cd` has been executed, and by that time, `%CD%` has already been installed into the command - as it stood when the `cmd.exe` was invoked.